# Retrieve Sharedposts with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to get shared posts of a photo of my page using:

> Photo_ID/sharedposts

But whenever I tried, it returns an empty data set.

I have already added "manage_pages" permission but it doesn't seem to work. The Graph API said that :

> A post will be returned if either (a) the app created the post or (b) the creator of the post has granted user_posts permission to the app.

So I'm not quite understand what it says but I assume that each person who shares my post have to grant "user_posts" permission to my app in order for it to read.

So for my circumstance: Getting all posts that shared my page post. Is there any permission for me to do this or do I have to configure any thing in my app?